# PHP - Detect change on an object from another

Tags: php, oop, error-handling

I am trying to handle errors generated by users from my entities objects.
In order to do that, I have a `errors` attribute in my entities objects.

My current problem is, some entities have entities as attributes, so those sub-entities also have `errors` attribute.

```js
class Entities
{
  protected $errors = [];
  
  // methods...
}

class User extends Entities
{
  protected $nick
            $someStuff;

  public function setNickName($val)
  {
    if (empty($val))
    {
      $this->errors[] = 'Incorrect nick';
    }
    
    $this->nick = $val;
  }
  
  public function getNickName()
  {
    return $this->nick;
  }
  
  public function setSomeStuff(EntityObj $val)
  {
    $this->someStuff = $val;
  }
  
  public function getSomeStuff()
  {
    return $this->someStuff;
  }
}

class EntityObj extends Entities
{
  protected $something;
  
  public function setSomething($val)
  {
    if //some verifications
    {
      $this->errors[] = 'problem';
    }
    
    $this->something = $val;
  }
}
```

**What I would like to do, would be to get `errors` attribute of my sub-entity to put them into my `errors` main entity's attribute, so I can retrieve all errors easily in my controller.**

Is it possible to detect changes on my `errors` var from the subentity, and then to put it on my `errors` main entity? So far, I am having a hard time doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to store your errors in the entities itself.
I don't know what version of PHP you use here, so I want to give you some ways to go. 
If you write your code in > PHP 7, then you should work with typehints. That prevents this Entity to work with null values at least.

You can transform your code from

```
public function setNickName($val)
  {
    if (empty($val))
    {
      $this->errors[] = 'Incorrect nick';
    }

    $this->nick = $val;
  }
```

to

```
public function setNickName(string $val)
{
    $this->nick = $val;
}
```

But I guess you don't want empty strings as Nickname too or want to have more verifications. Your expectation of usage for this Class is not fulfilled in that case, so it should maybe raise an exception? Everytime your expectations are not fulfilled for your application and something is not right, than it should raise an exception.

```
public function setNickName(string $val)
{
    if($this->nick === ''){
        throw new \UserException('Empty Nickname is not allowed.')
    }
    // more verification, more exceptions ...

    $this->nick = $val
}
```

But as you can guess, this is a problem many developers came across. Have a look e.g. at this validator component of an often used framework https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/validator.html .

tl;dr: 
Remove the errors property, you don't have to store errors in your entity itself. 
Start using typehints if you use PHP 7 or higher to prevent code for validation, php can handle it parts of itself.
Maybe use existing libraries to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The purpose of creating an error attribute is to be able to inform the user of what he did wrong. So, for a multiple fields form, every field he didn't complete right, an error list has to be shown. If I use exceptions, the code will stop after the first thrown exception (right?), which is not what I want. Same goes for typehints... I want my code to analyze all $_POST variables and then inform the user of what he did wrong

Comment: In my perspective the User class you‘ve written should store the data for the User and it maybe instantiate a valid state of the User everytime. With that approach your User class would have only one  purpose  - storing valid User data. If it stores errors and handle the validation of it, then it would have more than one purpose. So it would be a better idea to separate these actions.

Comment: It would maybe a good idea to store the data incoming in a different object and validate it with some sort of validator, which takes the data and tries to apply it one property by property into your User Class. The errors that it recieves can be returned as a List. Maybe think about that approach.